# Insert Text in holo circular progress bar

Tags: android

I'm using a Holo Circular ProgressBar library in my android application.

I want to write text in the center of a circle.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a TextView and place it on top of the circular progress bar in your layout.xml
fill it with text from your activity or fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Platform implementation does not support that.

Comment: Okey ,Thank you .. what do you suggest me to do ?